# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. potracelib.h not found with M1 chip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to install a Rails 5 app in my Macbook Air with M1 chip. This app is using a gem called `potracer`.

After doing `$ bundle install` I get the error:

```
Installing potracer 1.1.4 with native extensions
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/potracer-1.1.4/ext/potracer
/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/ruby -I /Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20211025-1533-nnxnj9.rb extconf.rb
checking for potracelib.h... no
potracelib.h not found
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --with-potrace-dir
    --without-potrace-dir
    --with-potrace-include
    --without-potrace-include=${potrace-dir}/include
    --with-potrace-lib
    --without-potrace-lib=${potrace-dir}/lib

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/2.7.0/potracer-1.1.4/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/gems/potracer-1.1.4 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.2/extensions/arm64-darwin-20/2.7.0/potracer-1.1.4/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing potracer (1.1.4), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install potracer -v '1.1.4' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  potracer
```

I had other issues installing other rails app with the M1 chip but I found workarounds but not in this case.

Ideas on how to solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to reinstall potrace loccaly before. The installation seems to be incomplete.

you would need the library/headers installed. Depending on your platform it would be something like libpotrace and libpitrace-dev.

You would install them via homebrew, apt, dnf, etc.

The potrace execution will abort unless you get the potrace.h locally

> abort  potracelib.h not found' unless find_header('potracelib.h')

```
    require 'mkmf'

RbConfig::MAKEFILE_CONFIG['CC'] = ENV['CC'] if ENV['CC']

LIBDIR = RbConfig::CONFIG['libdir']
INCLUDEDIR = RbConfig::CONFIG['includedir']

HEADER_DIRS = ['/opt/local/include', '/usr/local/include', INCLUDEDIR,
               '/usr/include']

LIB_DIRS = ['/opt/local/lib', '/usr/local/lib', LIBDIR, '/usr/lib']

dir_config('potrace', HEADER_DIRS, LIB_DIRS)

abort 'potracelib.h not found' unless find_header('potracelib.h')
abort 'lib potrace not found' unless find_library('potrace', 'potrace_version')

create_header
create_makefile('potracer/potracer')
```

Source: https://github.com/kennyp/potracer/blob/b67d3ff6a1ae672ccc6701fa5245fa532b461ef3/ext/potracer/extconf.rb